# I want to show and hide table column search filed

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have have data table and search filed for each column.
now i apply the show and hide column through mobile jquery.
it's working fine but the problem is when i uncheck the one column then column is hide but search filed for this column is not hidden `enter code here`         $('#myTable thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#myTable thead' );

```
    $('#myTable thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {

        let title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" style="max-width: 70px;" placeholder="Search" />' );

        $( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if (window.table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
                window.table
                    .column(i)
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please inspect and check your table structure where is input field is append then try to re-order your table structure it will solve your problem. If you don't understand what I have said then please upload your table screenshot. No one cannot solve this problem without seeing table structure.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/FDbGu6Kgai-J
Please check this screenshot

Comment: it's showing like this when i hide column
https://prnt.sc/f8zIRgYlW96B

Comment: nothing show in  this url

Comment: Please check this link.
https://crm.stonetree.ae/~xh1LO

Comment: please check this screenshot